# WINE not working on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wine, 17.04

I have installed wine stable and development from Ubuntu Store but neither is appearing. I am trying to run a screensaver .exe file but cannot. Pls recommend either how to get Wine to work or an alternative (PlayOnLinux doesn't work either)

Comment: Screensavers for windows probably won't work very well. Does running `winecfg`, `winecfg-stable` or `winecfg-development` show anything?

Comment: winecfg seems to actually fix it for a bit but when you try and run a program nothing happens

Comment: What does it fix (that was primarlily just to check if wine was installed). You could try running `wine /PATH/TO/FILE.exe` to run the app, and post any resulting output. Though the issue likely is that Ubuntu won't support running a screensaver that is a windows executable... I'm not even sure windows properly supports it. What app are you trying to use?

Comment: It opens the wine GUI. It opens the setup wizard, it actually seems like everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

I'll see that this Question is already kind a old. 
But if you still facing this Problem, then this might fixes it. 
If you installed Wine correctly from the offical WineHQ Website like followed the Instructions right, then you normally already can download an executable file and you can right click it or Open File with and select then "Open With Wine Windows Program Loader" and normally it should work then. That was actually for me so. So i am not pretty sure, if this will works also for you. But i hope so. I am currently on Linux Minut, but Linux Mint is the same as Ubuntu, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Just an FYI. Mint may be the same as Ubuntu in **this regard** but it would be fallacy to jump to that conclusion generally speaking.